# Is it possible to access android phone settings by selenium (appium) code?

Tags: android, selenium, testing, automation, appium

Is it possible to test automation strategy include turning wifi off and back on again using selenium on Appium?

Comment: Check this article: https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/how-to-deal-with-network-connection-in-appium-4-0-0-2134021fac25#.qq82xot95. It explains how to handle connection in appium >4.0.0 at the end of the article.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AndroidDriver `driver.setConnection(Connection conn)` method.

To switch off connection `driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE)` 
To switch on wifi connection `driver.setConnection(Connection.WIFI)`

http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/Connection.html

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
        ((AndroidDriver) dr).startActivity("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings","com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings");
```

// dr : object for android driver

For wifi :

```
        NetworkConnectionSetting ncs=new NetworkConnectionSetting(true,true,true);
        ncs.setWifi(false);  // true for turning on
```